# problems with shared project in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, file, reference

I work with my student group on a project :

We have some problems sharing our project.
There are 2 files that we have to modify everytime :

- project.properties
- private.properties

The Problem is, that we use librarys and they are relative paths to our hard drives.
so when we check out : we have to modify these files to get the project work :
Example :
C:\Users\**\Desktop\teddpee\EgisPartnerprofile\nbproject\build-impl.xml:519: Warning: Could not find file C:\vol\netbeans-6.1\6.1\enterprise5\modules\ext\jsf-1_2\jsf-impl.jar to copy.

C:\vol\netbeans-6.1\6.1\enterprise5\modules\ext\jsf-1_2\jsf-impl.jar is the path from someone other..
how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can do.

Establish a convention that everyone on the project uses and stick to it.  Maybe you can have everyone create c:\jars directory and put all their common JARs there.

Or you can learn [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or Ivy and let them handle your dependencies for you.

Comment: To : 1. We program on different platforms
To : 2. I guess i don't have enough time to learn it properly -> deadline 10th july

Comment: 1. Gotta figure out a way to share or don't share.  Agree on workable standards. 2. True, not enough time.  Shared it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans 6.1 added "Shared Libraries".  The Library Manager can manage libraries with relative references to the project.  Prior to 6.1, the Library Manager only managed personal libraries.

For example, if you project is in `${user.home}/OurProjects/TheProject` you could place your shared library in `${user.home}/OurProjects/SharedLibs`.  Then commit both to your VCS system. Team members can then update the library via the VCS.   In our environment this works fine for developers on Windows, OS X and Linux.

The IDE will help you convert a project from personal libraries to shared.

Here is some more info: http://www.netbeans.org/kb/61/java/library-sharing.html